# Query for get category in view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get the category from my article.

A category can have several sub categories, but I only want the first level. In my DataBase, each sub categories has a parent_id, stored in the same table.

[image]

I have a method scopeFirstLevelItems but I don't think it will help me here?

```
public function scopeFirstLevelItems($query)
{
    return $query->where('depth', '1')
                 ->orWhere('depth', null)
                 ->orderBy('lft', 'ASC');
}
```

It's possible to get the category parent from the sub categories ?

For get the category in my controller, I try this

```
protected function index(Article $article)
{

    $articles = Article::published()->paginate(8);
    $category = Category::with('articles')->firstLevelItems()->where('id', $article->id)->get();

    return view('pages.blog', [
        'articles' => $articles,
        'category' => $category
    ]);
}
```

And in my view

```
<a href="{{ $category->slug }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
```

But it doesn't work.

And I have three relations in my Category model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id');
}
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
}
```

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: I think that you need to `->orWhere('parent_id', null)` instead of `->orWhere('depth', null)`

Comment: Hello @hassan, I've edit my question. My request is a little different now

Comment: both `parent()` and `children()` are pointing to the same Model `Category`

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent category's name from child category by

```
$category->parent()->name
```

Also I think you copy pasted the child function to parent function.
Change the Model, which currently point to `App\Models\Category` in both parent and child.